How to detect mouse button press down and release in flutter flame?
I want to be able to detect if a mouse button is currently pressed down or not. All the sources suggested using a combination of onTapDown/onDragStart and onTadUp/onDragEnd functions, but onTapUp does not get triggered if I start dragging, and onDragEnd is called when I stop moving the mouse after dragging even if the key is still pressed, making it impossible to detect if the mouse key is pressed or not.
I tried to search through the flutter flame documentations, hoping to find something, but I could't.

That's odd that it call onDragEnd before you have released the button, does it call onTapUp once you release it? Which platform is this on?

It doesn't call any onTap events. Once you enter drag mode the onTap sequence gets hijacked.
